# On Click error? Start a New Activity or in including another activity?

Tags: android, onclick

I have a Application in that I want to add QR reader as a Activity/Module

So,I followed [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView) to Read QR code..
and Here Its working fine..

So I have added this code to My application and I want to use this activity for that I have designed a new activity in that On-click it should start Qr reader..

But I am getting this error...

Here I Tried with this

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(Qdata.this,DecoderActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }
```

**Here DecoderActivity.calass is northig But another application or activity which is Qr reader form the above example so I want to Include this in my activity....**

This at Manifest

```
   <activity
        android:name=".adata.Qdata"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="com.my.adata.Qdata" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".adata.DecoderActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="com.my.adata.DecoderActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Actually here adata is a another package in my Application... and Main package is com.my

So in com.my I have another files for QR purpose I have separated this two activities

This is Error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my/com.my.adata.DecoderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
at com.my.adata.DecoderActivity.onCreate(DecoderActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can any one suggest me what is problem...

Comment: share your error log here with qdata activity code

Comment: Post your exact stacktrace

Comment: add complete error log

Comment: whats on line 43 in Qdata.class, check there for nulll error

Comment: post code on line 43

Comment: On line 43 is nothing but a Activity which is [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView) code .. Its working fine when I run as a separate application but I want to use this on click in my application.. I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Do this changes in manifest...

```
    <activity
            android:name="com.my.adata.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">    
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.my.adata.Qdata"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
           <intent-filter>
           <action   android:name="com.my.adata.Qdata" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Sorry Same Problem I am getting Same error..Here Qdata in a separate Activity is working fine but If I Include this in my Activity I am getting same error

Comment: @don't be negative in Qdata activity you are getting null pointer so please check this null pointer

Comment: Here Qdata.calass is northig But another application or activity which is Qr reader form the above example so I want to Include this in my activity

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two launcher activity try to make one louncher activity and than call your activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".adata.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.my.adata.Qdata">
</activity>
```

Comment: Actually Here Launcher is another Activity But even If I changed it to Launcher also I am getting same error